# Python mock swallows exceptions

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I'm using python mock library (python 2.7, mock==1.0.1) and when mocking out certain parts of code that I'm testing mock is swallowing exceptions for some reason.

Below is an example:

```
#test.py
from django import test
from something import main_func
class TestCase(test.TestCase):
  @mock.patch('something.somewhere')
  def test_something(mock_somewhere):
    main_func()


#something.py
def somewhere(param):
  print param

def main_func():
  somewhere(None.missing_something)
```

So `AttributeError` should be raised right? This test is passing on my machine, in reality the code is more complicated, a Django Model is supposed to be saved and existing. The test is failing because the model doesn't exist.

If I insert an `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` just before `somewhere(None.missing_method)` then I can see the `AttributeException` is raised but it doesn't show up in the test.

Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity ... does your unit test file have a `if __name__ == '__main__': unittest.main()` line at the end?

Comment: Please fix your code that cannot be run: there are too much error to understand where is the cause. I've fixed test class parent `(unittest.TestCase)` and test arguments by `self,mock_somewhere` and it raise exception as expected.  Anyway if you see the exception in debugger but test don't grab it my guess is that you have more threads and the exception is not in your test thread but in an other one.

Comment: I've added 1 line and now this code can be run. I mentioned Django Models, this is a valid test case in Django and is discovered by it's test runner, I don't need a `__name__`. This isn't using any Threads of anything, it's just a normal django app and the methods that are being tested are just utility methods that operator on `Model` instances.

Comment: @DominicSantos AFAIK the signature of `test_something` is wrong: you forgot `self`

Comment: I cut and paste your code in a new django project, fixed `test_something` signature by add `self` as first argument and I cannot reproduce your issue. On my side `somewhere(None.missing_something)` raise an exception as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a 'spec' eg `autospec=True`

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html

This will then ensure that the generated mock will raise attribute errors if you try to access an attribute that didn't exist on the original object, otherwise mock will just return a new mock for any attr access

eg

```
from something import main_func

class TestCase(test.TestCase):
  @mock.patch('something.somewhere', autospec=True)
  def test_something(mock_somewhere):
    main_func()
```

Comment: `autospec=True` is even a good advice but it cannot be related to the question where he type `None.missing_something` and `None` is not a patched instance.

Comment: true, I just assumed code in question wasn't a complete real example and underlying problem was something like this